# Getting all products without associated products

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, products, configurable-product

I'm gonna tell my problem with example.

In my store 
I have 1 simple product: (aaaa)

And also I have a configurable products, with associated 4 products. (test)
Associated: 1 (test-small)
Associated: 2 (test-medium)
Associated: 3 (test-large)
Associated: 4 (test-xlarge)

These 4 associated products looking simple products on admin page, right?

I have a code base for getting all products below here:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id=entity_id', null, 'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('size', array('in'=>$size))
        ->addAttributeToFilter($roomfilter)
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
        ->setPage($pageNumber, $productPerPage)
        ->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
```

This code get all simple products. In this example getting: aaaa, test-small, test-medium, test-large, test-xlarge.

But I want to get aaaa and test products, not associated. How can I do that?

Comment: Change visibility of associated product to Not visible Individually.

Comment: This method hide associated products but I still cant get "test" (configurable) product. @Mufaddal

Comment: try to comment this condition and check ->addAttributeToFilter('size', array('in'=>$size))

Comment: @Mufaddal thank you so much, I forgot this filter :'/

Comment: But @Mufaddal I realized a problem in here. If I want to filter small size I still want to get only "test" product, not "test-small"